# PNP CORE SDK : How to get the file properties of a list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-core-sdk

Here is my request working with SHAREPOINT REST API:

```
_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Commercial')/Items?$expand=File&$select=Id,File/ServerRelativeUrl
```

I want to do the equivalent of this with PNP CORE SDK, I did this:

```
IList listCommercial = pnpCoreContextProject.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Commercial");                                            
foreach (var item in listCommercial.Items.QueryProperties(
    i => i.File.QueryProperties(f => f.ServerRelativeUrl))
    ){
       Log(item.File.ServerRelativeUrl);
    }
```

and I get:

> Property ServerRelativeUrl was not yet loaded:    à
> PnP.Core.Model.TransientObject.GetValue[T](String propertyName)    à
> PnP.Core.Model.SharePoint.File.get_ServerRelativeUrl()

Any idea why ? How should I do this ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure, but it might be the nested QueryProperties that creates the issue. If you rewrite slightly it will work:

```
IList listCommercial = _pnpContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
var files = listCommercial.RootFolder.Files.QueryProperties(f => f.ServerRelativeUrl);
foreach (var file in files)
{
    Console.WriteLine(file.ServerRelativeUrl);
}
```

Note that results will be paged so that you will only get the first 100 results unless you explicitly specify something else in your query